# azuredevops YAML setting step property from system variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to set this step's "enabled" property in YAML but it keeps on setting it to false. The rule is simple: Set to false on any rerun. So basically, this is only enabled on the first attempt.

Here is what i have so far:

```
   - task: PowerShell@1
     displayName: 'thepowershell'
     inputs:
      scriptName: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/drop/Infrastructure/Utility/Load.ps1'
      arguments: '"$(DeploymentDatabase)"'
     enabled: ${{ eq(variables['System.JobAttempt'],'1')}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `condition:` property, not the `enabled:` one if you want to skip the task completely.

The condition looks fine, though you may want to put `gt(... , 1)` to make sure the job is skipped in a 3rd or 4th attempt as well.

You probably also want to add a check for succeeded to also skip the task in case a previous step has failed:

```
condition: and( succeeded(), gt( variables['system.jobattempt'], 1) )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is totally expected behavior. And this is not able to achieve for now.

**Reason:**

**'System.JobAttempt' is not able to get it in the 'condition expression' part.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion

> Conditionals only work when using template syntax.

But 'System.JobAttempt' is not available in this situation:

[image]

If you were using 'Build.SourceBranch', you will successful to get the value:

```
trigger:
- none


steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Write your PowerShell commands here.
      
      Write-Host "Hello World"
      Write-Host $(Build.SourceBranch)
  enabled: ${{ eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')}}
```

Because it is available in this situation:

[image]

Successful to pass the condition template expression on my side when taking this variable:

[image]

You can refer to this page(predefined variables):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

If you need it, you can post a feature request here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion

Comment: This isn't running in a template. The snippet is from a straight yaml file without template invocation.

Comment: @jessehouwing The point is not 'to use the template or not'.

I am talking about [template expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#template-expressions) (`{{something here}}`)

The condition expression is using template syntax, which is processed at compile time. So, just variables that available in template can be used in condition expression.

Based on Predefined variable document, the 'System.JobAttempt' is not available in templates. So, you can’t use it like that.

Comment: @jessehouwing You can check jessehouwing's answer, maybe that is what you want? But, I think `{{}}` will be unable to get the value you want. Sorry I didn't post the predefined variables documentation earlier, I updated the answer.